# Mysql8 upgrade: one table has developed a problem with null constraints

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-8.0

We carried out an upgrade of a production system recently, from mysql5.7 to mysql8.

This was extensively tested on CI, local environments, staging. All queries ran as expected. With the move to mysql8 on prod just one table has developed a bizarre problem. It can be quantified as:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'my_col' cannot be null' with query:
'UPDATE my_table SET my_col = '1' WHERE table_id='abc123' LIMIT 1;'
```

The column is a varchar with `not null` and no default. But as you can see from the query, we are not *trying* to set it as null. We're trying to set it as a string "1". This error does not happen every time the query is run; it seems that if the application runs it twice in two subsequent requests it will work properly the second time.

To make this even more fun, this issue only occurs when run via our web application (PHP using PDO) - running this in mysql-client CLI works fine. The query fails via the web application both using parameterised queries and also if the whole query including inputs (which is insecure yes) is supplied as a single string query.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: There are triggers. We removed the update trigger but this persisted. However it seems that there's an open bug in mysql >=8.0.27 that causes updates to fail if an insert trigger is present: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113464

Comment: Sounds like you should use 8.0.26 and postpone any further upgrades until they fix that bug. And hope they don't introduce any other regressions in the meantime.

Comment: Can't downgrade prod unfortunately! However we seem to have a workaround, just testing

Comment: Glad you found a workaround, but this kind of regression bug makes me seriously uneasy about continuing to use MySQL! 

Comment: Yeah, it's in some ways very edge case so I can see how it escaped QA/CI, but their response is pretty poor - acknowledged over 2 months ago and no fix update. Plus it was introduced in a much older version.

Comment: Even worse, mysql team had this reported in 2022 but the person triaging was really unpleasant to the reporter https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108155. Not a good look; guess Oracle really do want to kill mysql as a product?

Comment: The MySQL verification team has one person who is famously rude to everyone. I don't know why they keep that individual in a customer-facing role. The other members of the team are more professional.

Answer (score 7):

Ok so this was fun. Turns out it's this bug from mysql 8 versions 8.0.27 and updwards (as of the time of this post there's no fix, and it's present in the current version 8.0.36). There's two code-level workarounds (see below)

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113464

Here's what explains the sporadic nature (i.e. a user tries again and it works) and why the bug didn't happen for us on testing or CLI.

- The bug occurs if a table has a trigger `ON INSERT` (before or after)
- However it only actually causes a problem on an `UPDATE` query to the same table
- And specifically the `UPDATE` must be run over the same connection to the database as the `INSERT`

Thus when we recreated any of this via CLI, that's a different connection as it's going via a bastion server. And when users hit submit repeatedly, the chances are that multiple requests land on different hosts, which have their own connection pools. It was sporadic (sometimes it took them 2 or 3 requests) because PDO caches connections within mod_apache, so multiple requests to one server may re-use the same connection.

Fixes (at present until mysql release a proper patch):

- Don't use an `INSERT` trigger (may not be feasible) if you intend to `UPDATE` the same row soon after (within the same request or using connection pools)
- Flush your table before making a subsequent `UPDATE` request:

```
try {
  $pdo->exec('FLUSH TABLES my_table');
}
catch (\Throwable $e){
  // log this in case it fails
}

// run your update here and the error won't happen
```

If the `FLUSH` command fails check that your database user has `FLUSH` or `RELOAD` privileges (alongside all other current privileges).